# Run apache with 2 PC's(HD,processor)

Tags: apache, load-balancing

If my site is used by many users, it becomes slow. How do I make my site to use two or more PCs?

Comment: There are things like load balancing, but that is a bit more complicated than simply using some command. Usually it is a good idea to make one step after another, not 10.000 steps at one time. So I would suggest you first operate http servers and implement applications on it, then you take care of optimizations of the performance, then maybe you think of more complex setups. Have fun :-) And if you really want to try out something _now_, then in 99% of all cases the best solution is to use a more powerful computer.

Comment: Are you taking about load balancing?

Answer (score 0):

Usually httpd is not aware of any load balancing in front of it. Check out things like LVS (linux virtual server) or haproxy or even nginx for examples of things you can put in front of httpd to scale it horizontally.